# Calculation order of bitwise operators in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I can't find information about calculation order of bitwise operators in Kotlin. Is it same as in Java or they compute from left to right without any priority?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `and`, `or` `xor` and other [infix functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation) for bitwise operations are not operators per se, and their execution order is the same as that of other infix functions, i.e. from left to right, so these two lines are equivalent:

```
a or b and c or d and e
```

```
(((a or b) and c) or d) and e
```

Also note that the precedence of the infix functions is lower than that of operators:

```
1 + 2 and 3 + 4
```

```
(1 + 2) and (3 + 4)
```